# Difference between an interval and a set of intervals?

Tags: algorithm, go, set, intervals, set-difference

I have a set of non-overlapping, non-adjacent intervals, eg. [{10,15}, {30,35}, {20,25}]. They are not sorted, but I can sort them if necessary.

Now I am given some new interval, eg. {5,32} and want to generate a new set of intervals describing the difference: the ranges covered by this new interval that aren't in the set. In this example the answer would be: [{5,9}, {16,19}, {26,29}].

What's a fast algorithm for calculating this? Note that the set will typically have 1, sometimes 2, rarely 3 or more items in it, so I want to optimise for this case.

For context, here's the code for initially creating the set from an input stream of start+end data, where I merge as I go:

```
type Interval struct {
    start int
    end   int
}

func (i *Interval) OverlapsOrAdjacent(j Interval) bool {
    return i.end+1 >= j.start && j.end+1 >= i.start
}

func (i *Interval) Merge(j Interval) bool {
    if !i.OverlapsOrAdjacent(j) {
        return false
    }
    if j.start < i.start {
        i.start = j.start
    }
    if j.end > i.end {
        i.end = j.end
    }
    return true
}

type Intervals []Interval

func (ivs Intervals) Len() int           { return len(ivs) }
func (ivs Intervals) Swap(i, j int)      { ivs[i], ivs[j] = ivs[j], ivs[i] }
func (ivs Intervals) Less(i, j int) bool { return ivs[i].start < ivs[j].start }

func (ivs Intervals) Merge(iv Interval) Intervals {
    ivs = append(ivs, iv)
    merged := make(Intervals, 0, len(ivs))
    for _, iv := range ivs {
        for i := 0; i < len(merged); {
            if iv.Merge(merged[i]) {
                merged = append(merged[:i], merged[i+1:]...)
            } else {
                i++
            }
        }
        merged = append(merged, iv)
    }
    return merged
}

func (ivs Intervals) MergeUsingSort(iv Interval) Intervals {
    ivs = append(ivs, iv)
    sort.Sort(ivs)
    merged := make(Intervals, 0, len(ivs))
    merged = append(merged, ivs[0])
    for i := 1; i < len(ivs); i++ {
        last := len(merged) - 1
        if !merged[last].Merge(ivs[i]) {
            merged = append(merged, ivs[i])
        }
    }
    return merged
}

func (ivs Intervals) Difference(iv Interval) Intervals {
    // ???
    return ivs
}

func main() {
    var ivs Intervals
    for _, input := range inputsFromSomewhere { // in reality, I don't have all these inputs at once, they come in one at a time
        iv := Interval{input.start, input.end}
        diffs := ivs.Difference(iv) // not yet implemented...
        // do something with diffs
        ivs = ivs.Merge(iv)
    }
}
```

I find that the above Intervals.Merge() is 2x faster than MergeUsingSort(), so I wonder if there's also a simple non-sorting way of answering my question.

Comment: The order matters, so I don't see how you can do it without sorting in some way. `MergeUsingSort` is probably slower because you call `Sort` every time even though you only need to call it once. Why not just make being sorted a precondition for using Intervals?

Comment: How can the Sort only be called once? Every time I add a new Interval, doesn't it need to be sorted in to the correct place prior to the simplified merge loop?

Comment: I'm building Intervals using Merge() from a stream of unsorted start&end values; as I receive each start&end I need to know the difference of it to all prior start&ends. So I can't have a precondition of being sorted. See the updated main() function above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by the methods here, I don't understand why your MergeUsingSort method modifies the receiver value and returns a different slice. If Merge really doesn't need to be ordered, but Difference does, I'm not sure what you're asking. The fact that you can remove sorting from an algorithm that doesn't need it doesn't mean you can remove sorting from an algorithm that does.

Comment: Well ignore Merge/MergeUsingSort as that was only a side note, but how would you implement Difference()? My point in bringing up my Merge() was to illicit any non-sorting algorithms for my problem if one exists. If none exists, that's fine.

Comment: Have you tried just implementing the obvious first? Off the top of my head it seems like simply waking through the intervals from start to end should suffice, e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/UzmZM8GaZR (untested besides the input/output provided)

Comment: Doesn't work with Intervals{{7, 10}} and ivs.Difference(Interval{20, 30}); expecting {20, 30}, gives {11, 30}. I now have a working solution of my own, so might take this to code review instead.

Comment: well, it was just written off the top of my head, and I missed the conditional on the start value. You can see though that there's not much to the basic algorithm other than walking up the start/end pairs in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question and answer code is incomplete and doesn't compile. There are no benchmarks. From a quick glance at the code, it's likely inefficient.

Usable code for `interval.go` and `interval_test.go` was obtained from https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/wr/tree/develop/minfys.

Let's start by writing a benchmark for the interval difference example.

```
package minfys

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

// Example
var (
    xA = Intervals{{10, 15}, {30, 35}, {20, 25}}
    xB = Interval{5, 32}
    xD = Intervals{{5, 9}, {16, 19}, {26, 29}}
    xR = Intervals{}
)

func BenchmarkExample(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    a := make(Intervals, len(xA))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(a, xA)
        xR = a.Difference(xB)
    }
    b.StopTimer()
    if fmt.Sprint(xD) != fmt.Sprint(xR) {
        b.Fatal(xD, xR)
    }
}
```

Next, write a Difference method.

```
package minfys

func (a Intervals) Difference(b Interval) Intervals {
    // If A and B are sets, then the relative complement of A in B
    // is the set of elements in B but not in A.
    // The relative complement of A in B is denoted B ∖  A:
    //     B \ A = {x ∈ A | x ∉ B}
    //     B \ A = B ∩ A'
    //
    // For example. d = a\b,
    //     a: [{10, 15}, {30, 35}, {20, 25}]
    //     b: {5,32}
    //     d: [{5,9}, {16,19}, {26,29}]
    // The elements of set a are non-overlapping, non-adjacent,
    // and unsorted intervals.

    if len(a) <= 0 {
        return Intervals{b}
    }

    d := make(Intervals, 0, 3)
    for ; len(a) > 0; a = a[1:] {
        for i := 1; i < len(a); i++ {
            if a[i].Start < a[0].Start {
                a[i], a[0] = a[0], a[i]
            }
        }

        if b.Start < a[0].Start {
            if b.End < a[0].Start {
                d = append(d, b)
                break
            }
            d = append(d, Interval{b.Start, a[0].Start - 1})
            b.Start = a[0].Start
        }
        if b.End <= a[0].End {
            break
        }
        if b.Start <= a[0].End {
            b.Start = a[0].End + 1
        }
        if len(a) == 1 {
            if b.Start <= a[0].End {
                b.Start = a[0].End + 1
            }
            d = append(d, b)
            break
        }
    }
    return d
}
```

Now, benchmark the Difference method.

```
BenchmarkExample-4     20000000     62.4 ns/op    48 B/op      1 allocs/op
```

sbs wrote a Difference method.

```
// Interval struct is used to describe something with a start and end. End must
// be greater than start.
type Interval struct {
    Start int64
    End   int64
}

// Overlaps returns true if this interval overlaps with the supplied one.
func (i *Interval) Overlaps(j Interval) bool {
    // https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/range_overlap_in_two_compares.html
    return i.End >= j.Start && j.End >= i.Start
}

// Intervals type is a slice of Interval.
type Intervals []Interval

// Difference returns any portions of iv that do not overlap with any of our
// intervals. Assumes that all of our intervals have been Merge()d in.
func (ivs Intervals) Difference(iv Interval) (diffs Intervals) {
    diffs = append(diffs, iv)
    for _, prior := range ivs {
        for i := 0; i < len(diffs); {
            if left, right, overlapped := prior.Difference(diffs[i]); overlapped {
                if len(diffs) == 1 {
                    diffs = nil
                } else {
                    diffs = append(diffs[:i], diffs[i+1:]...)
                }

                if left != nil {
                    diffs = append(diffs, *left)
                }
                if right != nil {
                    diffs = append(diffs, *right)
                }
            } else {
                i++
            }
        }
        if len(diffs) == 0 {
            break
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Benchmark sbs's Difference method.

```
BenchmarkExample-4      5000000    365 ns/op     128 B/op      4 allocs/op
```

peterSO's Difference method is significantly faster.

```
old.txt (sbs) versus new.txt (peterSO):

benchmark              old ns/op     new ns/op     delta
BenchmarkExample-4     365           62.4          -82.90%

benchmark              old allocs     new allocs   delta
BenchmarkExample-4     4              1            -75.00%

benchmark              old bytes     new bytes     delta
BenchmarkExample-4     128           48            -62.50%
```

This is just a beginning. There are likely other improvements that can be made.

There were some errors in `interval_test.go`. `ShouldBeNil` is for pointers; `ShouldBeEmpty` is for collections. `ShouldResemble` does not handle set equality (two sets which contain the same elements are the same set). Change `ShouldResemble` order to match implementation dependent order.

```
$ go test
..........................................................................................................................x......................................................x................x
Failures:

  * interval_test.go 
  Line 247:
  Expected: nil
  Actual:   '[]'

  * interval_test.go 
  Line 375:
  Expected: 'minfys.Intervals{minfys.Interval{Start:5, End:6}, minfys.Interval{Start:31, End:32}, minfys.Interval{Start:11, End:14}, minfys.Interval{Start:19, End:19}}'
  Actual:   'minfys.Intervals{minfys.Interval{Start:5, End:6}, minfys.Interval{Start:11, End:14}, minfys.Interval{Start:19, End:19}, minfys.Interval{Start:31, End:32}}'
  (Should resemble)!

  * interval_test.go 
  Line 413:
  Expected: 'minfys.Intervals{minfys.Interval{Start:7, End:10}, minfys.Interval{Start:1, End:3}, minfys.Interval{Start:15, End:17}}'
  Actual:   'minfys.Intervals{minfys.Interval{Start:1, End:3}, minfys.Interval{Start:7, End:10}, minfys.Interval{Start:15, End:17}}'
  (Should resemble)!


195 total assertions

...
198 total assertions

--- FAIL: TestIntervals (0.04s)
FAIL
```

.

```
$ diff -a -u ../interval_test.go interval_test.go
--- ../interval_test.go 2017-04-29 20:23:29.365344008 -0400
+++ interval_test.go    2017-04-29 20:54:14.349344903 -0400
@@ -244,19 +244,19 @@
            So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 1)

            newIvs = ivs.Difference(twoSix)
-           So(newIvs, ShouldBeNil)
+           So(newIvs, ShouldBeEmpty)
            ivs = ivs.Merge(twoSix)
            So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 1)

            newIvs = ivs.Difference(oneThree)
-           So(newIvs, ShouldBeNil)
+           So(newIvs, ShouldBeEmpty)
            ivs = ivs.Merge(oneThree)
            So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 1)

            oneSeven := Interval{1, 7}

            newIvs = ivs.Difference(oneSix)
-           So(newIvs, ShouldBeNil)
+           So(newIvs, ShouldBeEmpty)
            ivs = ivs.Merge(oneSix)
            So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 1)

@@ -372,7 +372,7 @@

            fiveThirtyTwo := Interval{5, 32}
            newIvs = ivs.Difference(fiveThirtyTwo)
-           So(newIvs, ShouldResemble, Intervals{Interval{5, 6}, Interval{31, 32}, Interval{11, 14}, Interval{19, 19}})
+           So(newIvs, ShouldResemble, Intervals{Interval{5, 6}, Interval{11, 14}, Interval{19, 19}, Interval{31, 32}})
            ivs = ivs.Merge(fiveThirtyTwo)
            So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 3)

@@ -409,7 +409,7 @@

            ivs = ivs.Truncate(17)

-           expected := Intervals{sevenTen, oneThree, Interval{15, 17}}
+           expected := Intervals{oneThree, sevenTen, Interval{15, 17}}
            So(ivs, ShouldResemble, expected)
        })
    })
```

.

```
$ go test
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................
205 total assertions

...
208 total assertions

PASS
$
```

---

> I [[@sbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675083/sbs)] confirm it's faster than my solution. Though if you just
>   measure the wall-time that using Difference() takes (put a before :=
>   time.Now() before the last Difference() call in the interval_test.go,
>   and a time.Since(before) after it and sum those durations over the
>   loop), it seems to make surprisingly little difference (on my machine
>   it takes ~31ms with my solution and ~29ms with yours).

As requested, `interval_test.go` was modified to measure wall time:

```
$ diff -a -u ../interval_test.go walltime_test.go
--- ../interval_test.go 2017-04-29 20:23:29.365344008 -0400
+++ walltime_test.go    2017-04-30 13:39:29.000000000 -0400
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "time"
+   "fmt"
 )

 func TestIntervals(t *testing.T) {
@@ -459,16 +460,20 @@

        var ivs Intervals
        errors := 0
+       var diffTime time.Duration
        t := time.Now()
        for i, input := range inputs {
            iv := NewInterval(int64(input), int64(readSize))
+           before := time.Now()
            newIvs := ivs.Difference(iv)
+           diffTime += time.Since(before)
            if (len(newIvs) == 1) != exepectedNew[i] {
                errors++
            }
            ivs = ivs.Merge(iv)
        }
-       // fmt.Printf("\ntook %s\n", time.Since(t))
+       fmt.Printf("took %s\n", time.Since(t))
+       fmt.Printf("\n  Difference took %s\n", diffTime)
        So(errors, ShouldEqual, 0)
        So(len(ivs), ShouldEqual, 1)
        So(time.Since(t).Seconds(), ShouldBeLessThan, 1) // 42ms on my machine
$
```

The `interval_test.go` benchmark input sizes and frequencies were

```
size    frequency
0       1
1       94929
2       50072
3       4998
```

Output sizes and frequencies were

```
size    frequency
0       50000
1       100000
```

Tuning peterSo's Difference method for this distribution gives

```
package minfys

func (a Intervals) Difference(b Interval) Intervals {
    // If A and B are sets, then the relative complement of A in B
    // is the set of elements in B but not in A.
    // The relative complement of A in B is denoted B ∖  A:
    //     B \ A = {x ∈ A | x ∉ B}
    //     B \ A = B ∩ A'
    //
    // For example. d = a\b,
    //     a: [{10, 15}, {30, 35}, {20, 25}]
    //     b: {5,32}
    //     d: [{5,9}, {16,19}, {26,29}]
    // The elements of set a are non-overlapping, non-adjacent,
    // and unsorted intervals.

    if len(a) <= 0 {
        return Intervals{b}
    }

    var d Intervals
    for ; len(a) > 0; a = a[1:] {
        for i := 1; i < len(a); i++ {
            if a[i].Start < a[0].Start {
                a[i], a[0] = a[0], a[i]
            }
        }

        if b.Start < a[0].Start {
            if b.End < a[0].Start {
                d = append(d, b)
                break
            }
            d = append(d, Interval{b.Start, a[0].Start - 1})
            b.Start = a[0].Start
        }
        if b.End <= a[0].End {
            break
        }
        if b.Start <= a[0].End {
            b.Start = a[0].End + 1
        }
        if len(a) == 1 {
            if b.Start <= a[0].End {
                b.Start = a[0].End + 1
            }
            d = append(d, b)
            break
        }
    }
    return d
}
```

Running the `interval_test.go` benchmark for peterSO's and sbs's Difference methods gives

```
$ go test -v

  Merging many intervals is fast took 26.208614ms

  Difference took 10.706858ms
```

and

```
$ go test -v

  Merging many intervals is fast took 30.799216ms

  Difference took 14.414488ms
```

peterSo's Difference method is significantly faster than sbs's: 10.706858ms versus 14.414488ms or minus 25.7 percent.

Updating the earlier example benchmark results for peterSO's revised Difference method gives

```
old.txt (sbs) versus new.txt (peterSO):

benchmark              old ns/op     new ns/op     delta
BenchmarkExample-4     365           221           -39.45%

benchmark              old allocs     new allocs   delta
BenchmarkExample-4     4              3            -25.00%

benchmark              old bytes     new bytes     delta
BenchmarkExample-4     128           112           -12.50%
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. The real code and a test script with sort-of real-world input to benchmark with is here: https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/wr/blob/develop/minfys/interval.go I tried your code and it didn't pass my tests. Probably something trivial to change but I didn't try fixing it yet.

Comment: @sbs: The real code is the key to solving the problem. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm it's faster than my solution. Though if you just measure the wall-time that using Difference() takes (put a `before := time.Now()` before the last Difference() call in the interval_test.go, and a `time.Since(before)` after it and sum those durations over the loop), it seems to make surprisingly little difference (on my machine it takes ~31ms with my solution and ~29ms with yours).

Comment: @sbs: I've revised my answer to include your wall time benchmark.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Actually, I didn't test your exact first method, but had changed `make(Intervals, 0, 3)` to `make(Intervals, 0, len(ivs))`, which I find to be almost consistently faster than your new variant of `var d Intervals`. But it's all very close and largely within the margin of error, so I think further optimisations are academic at this point.

Comment: No longer really on-topic for the question as I posed it, but my final solution is now up on github: the answer is of course to just keep the set sorted so that `Difference()` implementation can assume they are sorted, but without using an actual Sort (or your parital-sort) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here's my implementation of Difference() that is faster (on my input data) than eg. JimB's suggestion that required a sort.

```
func (i *Interval) Overlaps(j Interval) bool {
    return i.End >= j.Start && j.End >= i.Start
}

func (i *Interval) Difference(j Interval) (left *Interval, right *Interval, overlapped bool) {
    if !i.Overlaps(j) {
        return
    }

    overlapped = true
    if j.Start < i.Start {
        left = &Interval{j.Start, i.Start - 1}
    }
    if j.End > i.End {
        right = &Interval{i.End + 1, j.End}
    }
    return
}

func (ivs Intervals) Difference(iv Interval) (diffs Intervals) {
    diffs = append(diffs, iv)
    for _, prior := range ivs {
        for i := 0; i < len(diffs); {
            if left, right, overlapped := prior.Difference(diffs[i]); overlapped {
                if len(diffs) == 1 {
                    diffs = nil
                } else {
                    diffs = append(diffs[:i], diffs[i+1:]...)
                }

                if left != nil {
                    diffs = append(diffs, *left)
                }
                if right != nil {
                    diffs = append(diffs, *right)
                }
            } else {
                i++
            }
        }
        if len(diffs) == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    return
}
```

It works on the data I've tried, though I'm a little worried I might have missed an edge case where it gets the wrong answer.

Comment: The code for your implementation of `Difference()` is missing an `Overlaps` method (`!i.Overlaps(j)`). Please provide the `Overlaps` method code so that we can check your code and reproduce your results.

Comment: Sorry, Overlaps() now added. The code in this answer is an extension of the code in the question, so see the original post for other necessary things.